# Domain Name to Multiple IP Address Conversion

Tags: web, dns, ip, load-balancing

Google has multiple servers at multiple locations. When I search Google in my web browser, how does the DNS map this name to the corresponding IP address? Google has multiple servers in multiple locations with separate IPs. Is a load balancer used first?

Answer (score 2):

In large scale reverse proxy server is usually used for this purpose and it can do various tasks including load balancing as well. To the client it appears that you connect only to one server while reverse proxy hides servers behind it.

In small scale you can do similar things just with DNS settings mapping different domain names to different IP addresses. See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy)

Comment: different domain names can be mapped to different IP address what if only one domain name is to be mapped with many IP addresses

Comment: Then it is job for reverse proxy server

Answer (score 2):

A couple of different approaches are used:

### Geographic DNS

When a request comes in for a domain name, the DNS server looks at the IP address making the request and returns an IP address of a nearby server.

Some complicated extensions are required to deal with large shared caching DNS servers (like ISP nameservers), but that's the general idea.

### Anycast DNS

[Anycast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast) is a weird routing trick where a single IP range can be advertised by multiple ASes. This will cause requests to an IP address in that range to be routed to whichever server is closest.

If a DNS server is hosted on an anycast IP, different instances of that server can be configured to return different IPs. This can be used as a computationally easier alternative to geographic DNS.

### Anycast HTTP

If anycast can be used to route DNS to the closest server, why not just go to the next step and use it to route HTTP as well?

(It turns out there's a reason why you usually don't want to do this: Routing changes can break a HTTP connection. This doesn't affect DNS as it's usually used over UDP. Cloudflare does it anyway, though, and it usually works fine… YMMV.)